# Basic JQgrid question - how do I get the examples to work?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm trying to replicate the inline editing jqgrid examples given at 
http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

I have tried reading the documentation http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm
but I can't get the inline examples to work. .

What am I doing wrong? I have created the database and have the default example working.

My goal is to get the example for the inline editing working. Does anyone have any example script for the inline editing I could use for the html file and the php file?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Thanks,

Kanji